# Get filemtime for most recently updated file in folder

Tags: php, filemtime

I have a folder with 4 files in it and I'd like to pull the last modified time of the most recent one (which may not always be the same one). Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Iterate through all the files, hanging on to the one with the latest modified time.  Display the result at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to find the files and then simply compare their modified times. This oughta do it:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('path/to/dir');

$mtime = -1;
$file;
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mtime) {
            $file = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $mtime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to iterate through the directory - [`filemtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) will work for most servers, (depending on your configuration):

```
$LastMod = filemtime("/path/to/dir/.");
```

The last dot is needed to see the directory as a file and to actually get a last modification date of it.

Comment: According server configuration lastmod on directories will be updated according children files... or not :(

Comment: Using PHP7 on an Ubuntu server getting filemtime on a folder will result in `Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for [folder]`