# How to update skin as I upload it

Tags: php, mediawiki, tableofcontents

Ive noticed that when I upload my skin file it doesn't update automatically. Is there anything i can do to make it so when i change my skin files it will change on the wiki instantly

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: Fixed it, Please take a look again

Comment: does the wiki cache? or it could just be your browser cache

Answer (score 1):

Set or update [`$wgCacheEpoch`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheEpoch). If you want to update automaticly, generate it from the last modification date of your skin files (see linked example). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767346/get-filemtime-for-most-recently-updated-file-in-folder) on getting the last modified date from multiple files.